# Sorting Cell Table column in GWT not working

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to sort a column in a Cell table of GWT 2.6.0, but it is not working.

Here is my sample Code.

```
patientsTable.addColumn(NameColumn, messages.surname());
patientsTable.setColumnWidth(0, "100px");
patientsTable.getColumn(0).setSortable(true);

        ListHandler<PatientDTO> columnSortHandler = new ListHandler<PatientDTO>(
                dataProvider.getList());
        columnSortHandler.setComparator(NameColumn,
                new Comparator<PatientDTO>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(PatientDTO o1, PatientDTO o2) {
                if (o1 == o2) {
                      return 0;
                    }

                    if (o1 != null) {
                      return (o2 != null) ? o1.getLastName().compareTo(o2.getLastName()) : 1;
                    }
                    return -1;
            }
            });
        patientsTable.addColumnSortHandler(columnSortHandler);
        patientsTable.getColumnSortList().push(NameColumn);
```

Comment: _"but it is not working"_. That's not really helpful. What's the problem? Do you get an error/exception? Does it simply not sort at all? Does it sort in the wrong order?

Comment: It is not sorting the column and there is no error or exception. @Baz

Comment: BTW: please use `equals()` to compare objects, not `==`.

Comment: I have replaced `==` with `equals()` but still it is not sorting.

Comment: Sorry if there was a misunderstanding, my previous comment was just a note, not an attempt to solve your problem. I don't see why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, using == in comparator is correct. You check if this is the same object.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Depends, they may be identical/equal although they aren't the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NameColumn.setSortable(true);
```

Comment: Do you add any other columns?

Comment: yes I do.
`patientsTable.addColumn(firstNameColumn, messages.forename() );
 patientsTable.setColumnWidth(1, "100px");
 DateCell dateCell = new DateCell(dtf);
 Column<PatientDTO, Date> dateColumn = new Column<PatientDTO, Date>(dateCell) {
     @Override
     public Date getValue(PatientDTO object) {
  return object.getBirthday(); 
     }
 };

 patientsTable.addColumn(dateColumn, messages.birthday());
 patientsTable.setColumnWidth(2, "100px");` @andrei

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, i have given working example,

```
  NameColumn.setSortable(true);

  patientsTable.addColumnSortHandler(new ColumnSortEvent.Handler() {
  @Override
  public void onColumnSort(ColumnSortEvent event) {
    final Column a = event.getColumn(); 
    List<PatientDTO> newData = new ArrayList(patientsTable.getVisibleItems());

      Collections.sort(newData, new Comparator<PatientDTO>() {
        public int compare(PatientDTO o1, PatientDTO o2) {
          // code here to sort asc or desc order
          }
      });

    Range range = patientsTable.getVisibleRange();  
    int start = range.getStart(); 
    patientsTable.setRowData(start, newData);  
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the same `List<PatientDTO>` instance which you are using while setting your data in the `patientsTable`. It seems that the sortHandler is not being called because of the difference  in both of the list.

```
ListHandler<PatientDTO> columnSortHandler = new ListHandler<PatientDTO>(patientList);
```